# How do I set password complexity?

Tags: security

I need to change the password complexity requirements for authors to meet corporate standards of a password being:

- Minium of 8 characters
- Contain at least one numeral
- Contain at least one symbol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set this in the `web.config`. In your membership section. You can set a password strength regular expression.

```xml
<add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
    connectionStringName="core" 
    applicationName="sitecore" 
    minRequiredPasswordLength="8" 
    minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
    requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
    passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{7,19}$" />
```

I found this regex `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{7,19}$` for your requirements: [Regex Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938415/regex-for-password-atleast-1-letter-1-number-1-special-character-and-should)

Comment: when I tried this I am getting this error:
   `Error Code    0x8007000d`
   `Config Error    Configuration file is not well-formed XML`

Comment: @Anjo please open a new question for further issues.